# guess number game in c ran into trouble

Tags: c

I'm new to c language, so excuse me if I make a stupid mistake. I'm trying to implement a mini game where you guess a secret number generated by the computer in C. Here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(void)
{
    int c=1;
    bool running = 1;
    int x = rand() % 20;
    printf("The secret number is between 0 and 19, take a guess\n");
    int inp = getchar();
    while (running) {
        if (inp==x) {
            printf("Correct. Total number of guesses you spent was %i. Would you like to start a new game? Y/n", c);
            bool running=0;
        }
        else if (inp>x) {
            printf("guess smaller\n");
            scanf("%i", inp);
        }
        else if (inp<x) {
            printf("guess larger\n");
            scanf("%i", inp);
        }
        c+=1;   
    }
}
```

After compiling, the game ran into trouble:

```
zhiwei@zhiwei-Lenovo-Rescuer-15ISK:~/workspace$ ./guess
The secret number is between 0 and 19, take a guess
3
guess smaller
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's "Segmentation fault"? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Could you please fix it?

Comment: Not your immediate concern, but ` bool running=0;` will *shadow* the variable defined at a higher scope.

Comment: How would `int inp = getchar();` read a two digit integer???

Comment: `scanf("%i", inp);`-> `scanf("%i", &inp);`

Comment: I saw this same code from another user today.Is it from some book?

Comment: `int inp = getchar();` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `scanf("%i", inp);` ==> `if (scanf("%i", &inp) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: It's probably time to start reading your C textbook. The program is overly complicated and wrong.

Comment: Usually, a "segmentation fault" occurs when your program attempts to access memory that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: `getchar()` gets a character, which is the ASCII representation of a single character typed at the input. So if you enter a `2`, `getchar` will return a value of 0x32.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks. Can you clarify what you mean by "shadow"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'll pick on a textbook as soon as possible. But I'd also like to get advice from you on this particular project. Is there a simpler implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Segmentation fault (core dumped) error due to this line:

```
scanf("%i", inp);
```

**scanf** method takes pointers as arguments. Now program is trying to write new value to memory which is not reserved for our program.

You should replace this line by:

```
scanf("%i", &inp);
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems with your code is that you are incorrectly using `scanf`. The first parameter of `scanf` is a format string, and any additional parameter should be a pointer, so:

```
// Incorrect
scanf("%i", inp);

// Correct
scanf("%i", &inp);
```

Segmentation faults happen when you are trying to access a memory address that is either invalid or you don't have the rights to access. Suppose you run your program, and the first number you write is 3, so `inp = 3`. Up until this point, everything runs OK, since you are reading the first number using `getchar`. But then, you use `scanf("%i", inp)` so `scanf` will write the next number at address `inp`, i.e, at address `3`, which is an address you cannot write in! Thus you get a segmentation fault.

---

There is another error in your code, a logic error though. You read your first number by using `getchar`: what if you want to input a number larger than 9? You should use `scanf` for the first read too.

```
...
printf("The secret number is between 0 and 19, take a guess\n");
int inp;

// Not good
inp = getchar();

// Good
scanf("%i", &inp);
...
```

---

Also, your `while` loop will never end, i.e., your program will run forever (unless you kill it). Indeed whenever this `if` block is executed:

```
if (inp == x) {
    printf("Correct. Total number of guesses you spent was %i. Would you like to start a new game? Y/n", c);
    bool running = 0;
}
```

You declare a new variable `bool running` that overwrites the previously declared `running` variable. You should just replace it with:

```
if (inp == x) {
    printf("Correct. Total number of guesses you spent was %i. Would you like to start a new game? Y/n", c);
    running = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried getchar() and it seemed to work fine. Do I missinterpret something?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I found that when getchar() is used, it won't work well for those larger than two digits because it will print "guess smaller" and guess "larger" consecutively when you guess wrong , though no problem for those with a single digit. But I still wonder why it behaves that way using getchar().

Comment: @pxc3110 the problems with `getchar` are two:
1) It reads only the first char of the number. This is OK only if you are reading numbers from 0 to 9, but in your case you are reading any number between 0 and 20.
2) It reads the ASCII table value of the first char. If you write `1`, then `inp = 49` (take a look at the ASCII table for the value of '1').
So if you write 15, then `getchar` will only read `1` and `inp = 49`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, which correctly point out the reason for the segmentation fault, you have many more problems.  The below does (I think) what you need:

```
int main()
{
    int c = 1;
    bool running = 1;
    srand(time(0));
    int x = rand() % 20;
    printf("The secret number is between 0 and 19, take a guess\n");
    int inp;
    scanf("%i", &inp);
    while (running) {
        if (inp == x) {
            printf("Correct. Total number of guesses you spent was %i. Would you like to start a new game? Y/N", c);
            char a;
            scanf(" %c", &a);
            if (a == 'N' || a == 'n')
            {
                running = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                c = 0;
                srand(time(0));
                x = rand() % 20;
                printf("The secret number is between 0 and 19, take a guess\n");
                scanf("%i", &inp);
            }
        }
        else if (inp>x) {
            printf("guess smaller\n");
            scanf("%i", &inp);
        }
        else if (inp<x) {
            printf("guess larger\n");
            scanf("%i", &inp);
        }
        c += 1;
    }
}
```

Things to note.  You need to give a seed value before calling rand() otherwise you will get a sequence of numbers in the same order.  Usually current time is a good enough seed.  Secondly you need to read in the answer to the question whether the user wished to continue or not and act accordingly.  Here you must not re-define running (with bool) otherwise you create a new variable rather than replace the value in the higher level variable.  Also note the use of a white space when prompting for a char (" c%").  This is necessary to avoid the program seeming to skip the input. Finally, you need to reset the counter and x if the user opts to continue.

Comment: This looks overly complicated.

Comment: @MichaelWalz What's the simpler way?

Comment: Note that this code doesn't check that `scanf()` success, so a typo such as a letter instead of a number will give it problems.

Comment: @pxc3110 you could have on single place to call `scanf("%i", &inp);`, and you can eliminate the variable `running`. It le you figure this out by yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see. Thank you for that one.